# Error: couldn't parse error string - why so?

Tags: android-studio, apk

I have a problem to my android studio in mac.
I developed an app and I generated and full app signed but in debug mode
when I want to generate release mode the apk build but when I want to install that in emulator or a device it doesn't work and I've got an error like this:

`couldn't parse error string`

and I think only here can find my answer
It doesn't have any log or any error exept this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you added long string in your XML or in your strings resource file,if so then make it small or divide it in small parts and then assign it by contaminating. Hope this work.

Comment: thanks it was my proplem . and I had not sign my app in two part of v1 and v2 then it works